# Regex group matching parameters with parantheses

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6

My data is like

```
new Abc(false, new G()), //SUCCESS
new Cba(true, new Fhhhhhfrrfr8()),//FAIL
new BZx(false, new zzZZ44d()) //SUCCESS
```

I'm trying to match the name of those types, the parameters and the commentary. So far I tried it with `new (.+)\((.+)\),? ?\/\/(SUCCESS|FAIL)`, but this yields Group 1 as `Abc(false, new G`, Group 2 as `)` and 3 as `SUCCESS`, however, I desire `Abc` as first group match, `false, new G()` as second and `SUCCESS` as third. The new instanciation kills my regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want any character (`.`) in your types, right? I think you can just include the letters, then it won't want to spill over into the parameters.

```
/new ([a-zA-Z]+)\((.+)\),? ?\/\/(SUCCESS|FAIL)/i
```

Give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
new ([^(]+)\(([^,]+),[\s]{0,}new[\s]{0,}([^(]+)\(\)\)[\s,]{0,}\/\/(SUCCESS|FAIL)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9RtsYa/1)